# Убрать скроллинг при dismissViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Привет!

При вызове `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated...]` на предыдущем экране `UIScrollView` скроллится в начало. Т.е. перехожу с экрана со `UIScrollView` через `[self presentViewController...]` и возвращаюсь обратно через `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Как выключить скроллинг? Запомнить позицию `UIScrollView` и при переходе обратно в методе `viewWillAppear` прокручивать `scrollView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может скролл не правильно приготовлен? Может вы реализовали загрузку скролла в методе `viewWillAppear` или `viewDidAppear` ? Так, как описанное вами поведение не присуще к UIScrollView.

Comment: Может быть это из-за того, что в `viewDidLayoutSubviews` прописан scrollView.contentSize?

Comment: Проверьте, на вскиду не скажу.. надо тестить.

Comment: Когда не известно, какая "зараза" меняет `contentOffset` скролла, можно использовать [KVO][1] в целях дебага, это здорово экономит время.


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html